# How to make method call present on UI Element?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I want to call method EnsureVisible present on RadTreeViewItem. I have implemented a behavior and used that behavior in TreeViewItemStyle.when I try to debug I am getting DataContext source instead of RadTreeViewItem as parameter for DependencyObject.

Could someone help me how to achieve this??

Comment: I don't know... Maybe try to cast to RadTreeViewItem? If not we can't do anything without seeing your code...

Comment: I tried to cast but I am getting my class object for example if my class name is Customer I am getting customer object on which EnsureVisible method not available.